# Why is that, when using CSS framework, all forms are 100% width by default?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, css-frameworks

And how can I work around it? I have just realized this -- or maybe it's unique me. No matter which CSS framework I use, forms occupy the entire width. I've tried resizing according to their keywords (e.g. "is-9" in Bulma), but none worked.

I created a section that wraps around the form that's written in ERB and wrote a CSS that sets max-width of that section.

Is this the only way to deal with this? Or is there a standard way that I'm missing? I cannot find any information related to this.

UPDATE:

Per the fantastic suggestions by the commenters, I have identified the specific CSS code within the CSS framework causing this, then I have overridden that code with my own in the application stylesheet.

This however seems cumbersome. Is this how CSS frameworks are used? Do they always set min-width as well as default width for forms to 100%?

Comment: Do you have a `*` or `body` class in your CSS stylesheet that you are applying styles to? Do a search in your Application CSS file and see if there is anything being set for `width: 100%` or to any kind of form elements.

Comment: @Jake So it is just me. No, the CSS stylesheets are clean. It's a rails app, and so far has some CRUDs with no styles other than what I wrote above

Comment: Open up the developer console in your browser. Look at the styles applied to your forms to see where the undesired behavior is coming from. Override it with your own CSS.

Comment: @jvillian Looks like in Bulma (CSS framework), both max and min width are set as 100%. I'll try changing min width.

Comment: The source code is... nightmare. Perhaps another way exists? I mean if this is caused by CSS framework -- multiple CSS frameworks I've tried do this --, then how do people solve this?

Comment: How are you rendering your stylesheets in your Application.html.erb layout? Make sure to render your application.css *after* the framework's stylesheet.

Comment: @Jake I have overriden the Bulma code (min width) with application stylesheet. Now it works. Thank you all! (I hope this is the standard way)

Comment: I would suggest you don't answer it yourself due to help from the comments. The comments are usually used to probe possible solutions to then become answers. Allow @jvillian to answer it if his suggestion was the most useful.

Comment: @Jake Happy to. Do you know if this the way others use CSS frameworks? Do such frameworks always set forms min-width to 100% by default?

Comment: I don't know, they can all be different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, I suggest you:

- Open up the developer console in your browser.
- Look at the styles applied to your forms to see where the undesired behavior is coming from.
- Override it with your own CSS.

As to whether this is how CSS frameworks are used, I don't have a definitive answer. But, in my experience, the answer is "yes" and having the ability to override more general behaviors (in the framework) with more specific ones (in your application) puts the "Cascading" in Cascading Style Sheets.